# protect only one folder in apache with password

Tags: apache

The question is that I want to protect only one folder "admin", I was using this in my .htaccess placed in /home/my_home/public_html

```
AuthName "message"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/my_home/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

but this protect all my site whilst I want to protect actually /home/my_home/public_html/admin. IN my error log I see:

```
/home/myhome/public_html/admin/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
```

Comment: try [this](http://www.addedbytes.com/blog/code/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess/)

Comment: put the file in /home/my_home/public_html/admin not /home/my_home/public_html

Comment: didnt work.....protect the whole site. I also moved the file to the other file, But no result

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the .htaccess file into your admin folder.

The configuration directives found in a .htaccess file are applied to the directory in which the .htaccess file is found, and to all subdirectories thereof. see [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#how)

Comment: yes, I knew that, but is not working.I have my .htaccess with those directives inside my admin folder...but nothing

Comment: Please ensure, that you've deleted the .htaccess file in your /home/my_home/public_html folder and that the .htaccess file in your admin folder is named correctly. Often people forget the dot in front of the filename. Furthermore a browser restart or page reload could help (strg + f5 on firefox)

Comment: I have to delete my htacces in public_html??

Comment: Yes, you have to delete the .htacess file inside your public_html folder. The only .htacess file you should have is the one in the admin folder.